# Solicitar ultimos datos guardados con php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, imagen

estoy haciendo un programa que suba imagenes a una base de datos con php, y quiero que cuando subas una imagen te mande a una tabla con la ultima imagen que guardaste, pero me muestra todas las imagenes anteriores, osea solo quiero ver el ultimo id, nombre e imagen.

CODIGO PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tabla.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif|Poppins|Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">
<head>
    <title>Mostrar imagenes</title>
</head>
<body>
   <center>
       <table id="mitabla" border="1">
       <thead>
       <tr>
          <th colspan="6"><a href="index.php" class="Titulo">Nuevo</a></th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <th>id</th>
           <th>Nombre</th>
           <th>Imagen</th>
           <th colspan="2">Opciones</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <?php
        include("conexion.php");

        $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen";
        $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td><img height="80px" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['Imagen']); ?>"/></td>
            <th><a href="modificar.php?Id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>">Modificar</a></th>
            <th><a href="eliminar.php?Id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>">Eliminar</a></th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        }

        ?>   
    </tbody>
</table>
   </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una opción sería mediante `DESC` y `LIMIT` añadiéndole a tu sentencia, quedaría algo así: `$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen DESC LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese código que subiste es un código para mostrar todas las imágenes.
Seguramente para cargar la imagen lo hiciste con un formulario, no? Este formulario en su tag de definición tiene un ACTION que es el archivo que procesa los datos y los sube, por ejemplo:
`<form method="POST" action="subir.php">`
La página "subir.php" recibe los datos y los graba en la base de datos, por ejemplo:

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$imagen... (bueno, no vas a grabar la imagen en la tabla sino que la vas a subir a un directorio)
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabla_imagen(id,nombre,imagen) VALUES ($id,$nombre,$imagen)");
```

Ahora ya tienes el ID guardado en una variable
 A continuación puedes poner el código que enviaste antes pero sólo con el ID de la imagen que subiste
`$query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE id=$id";`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero termine usando otro metodo, primero los ordene descendientemente y luego use el parametro LIMIT , pero de todas maneras gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder, lo aprecio mucho :)

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo con [$mysqli->insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) esto te devolvera el ultimo `id` insertado en tu base de datos.

**ejemplo:**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tabla_imagen VALUES(NULL,'{$nombre}','{$imagen}')";

if($conexion->query($query)){
 $last_insert = $conexion->insert_id;
}

// ahora tu query la cambias a
$query = "SELECT * FROM WHERE Id={$last_insert}";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
// resto de codigo
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero termine usando otro metodo, primero los ordene descendientemente y luego use el parametro LIMIT , pero de todas maneras gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder, lo aprecio mucho :)

Comment: Acabo de probar tu metodo y tambien funciona

Comment: @Jesús la ventaja de este metodo al  que utilizas es que si hay mucho volumen de transacciones el ultimo insert podria ser otra imagen ya que solo obtienes el ultimo resultado pero de cualquiera!... con estos minimizas el riesgo de que no valla a mostrar el resultado que no es.